# How to create a variable in a bash script that contains the data from a postgres database

Tags: bash, postgresql, variables, select

I'm looking to create a script than can find a specific date/time based on a field in a database
Currently i do it manually...

```
# psql gttvdb -U postgres
gttvdb=# select patch_date from version_history where version ='1.1.1';
```

What i need is to be able to reference that date as a variable in a bash script

```
#! /bin/sh
patchdate=$("select patch_date from version_history where version ='1.1.1';")
echo "last update was " $patchdate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
patchdate=` psql -t -q -c "select patch_date from version_history where version ='1.1.1'"`
```

Comment: read dtin
    patchdate=`psql gttvdb -U postgres -t -q -c "select patch_date from version_history where version = '$dtin' ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1;"`